# Are there nontrivial examples of "concrete" stable diffeomorphisms?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

This   is   related to my older  question 
[Tools for constructing homeomorphisms between 4-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309358/tools-for-constructing-homeomorphisms-between-4-manifolds) ,   but  it is much  more down to earth.
It is known  since 1960s  that for homotopy equivalent simply  connected smooth 4-manifolds $M$ and $N$ there is  $k$ such that $M\#k(\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2)$  is diffeomorphic to $N\#k(\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2)$.   Nowadays,   this diffeomorphism  may  be constructed  very explicitly using Kirby calculus, at least in theory.

However, there is a potential problem. This  classical   result of   Wall 
[Wall, C.T.C., On simply-connected 4-manifolds. J. London Math. Soc. Vol. 39 (1964), pp. 141–149.] consists of two parts. The first part (Theorem 2) is   "homotopy equivalent" $\Rightarrow$ "h-cobordant", the second part (Theorem 3)
is "h-cobordant" $\Rightarrow$ "stably diffeomorphic". As I understand it, the proof of the latter is not constructive, and gives no *a priory* upper bound on the number  $k$. In practical terms   it means no guarantee that you can  produce a genuine  stable diffeomorphism even in simplest cases.

So, I have two  questions. Did anyone   construct   a stable diffeomorphism beteween non-diffeomorphic closed simply  connected 4-manifolds using Kirby calculus?  (Or, at least, tried to.)  And, is there an effective version of the Wall's theorem about  h-cobordism?

[EDIT] This is nearly a duplicate of ([Non-trivial examples of Stably diffeomorphic 4-manifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264701/non-trivial-examples-of-stably-diffeomorphic-4-manifolds)), as Danny Ruberman pointed out. (That's embarrassing, I really should have checked this!) Maybe it is better to close it, I am not sure.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264701/non-trivial-examples-of-stably-diffeomorphic-4-manifolds. If you want to look at some nice handle pictures, try D. Auckly, ‘Families of four-dimensional manifolds that become mutually diffeomorphic after one stabilization’, Topol. Appl. 127 (2003) 277–298.  In all of the examples that anyone [that I know] knows, k can be taken to be 1, but there is no known upper bound.